# How to add HashMap<String, String> in Netbeans easyUML plugin

Tags: java, netbeans

In class diagram I am trying to add HashMap map as a field. But its showing following error. But its accepting ArrayList. So how can I add  in field with EasyUML.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the interface as the type rather than the implementing class?  Perhaps Map<String, String>.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with Map<String, String>. Unfortunately it also doesn't work.